# AdColony causes Force close during Vungle ad

Tags: android, admob, adcolony, vungle-ads

I have a problem. I implemented AdColony rewarded ads through Admob mediation. It works itself. Then I implemented Vungle rewarded ads also through Admob mediation. The problem is that AdColony requires each of Activities to have AdColony.Pause() and AdColony.Resume() in overridden (onPause, onResume) methods. Almost everytime I run Vungle ad I receive Force Close with informations below.
I see that my skills are not so sophisticated because I don't know how to deal with it. Interstitial ads works fine. Problem is only with rewarded ads. Could anyone advice what to do with it?
Problem could be new, because Google announced rewarded ads mediation on March 15th 2016.

```
03-31 20:38:42.869 19578-20093/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-107283
                                               Process: org.ovh.EmpireSTG, PID: 19578
                                               com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyException: AdColony.configure() must be called before any other AdColony methods. If you have called AdColony.configure(), the Activity reference you passed in via AdColony.configure()/AdColony.resume() is null OR you have not called AdColony.resume() as appropriate.
                                                   at com.jirbo.adcolony.a.b(SourceFile:181)
                                                   at com.jirbo.adcolony.a.e(SourceFile:222)
                                                   at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyV4VCAd.<init>(SourceFile:40)
                                                   at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter.a(SourceFile:427)
                                                   at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter$9.run(SourceFile:485)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing onResume and onPause in the Activity that launches the Ad did work for me:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  if (AdColony.isConfigured()) AdColony.resume( this );
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  if (AdColony.isConfigured()) AdColony.pause();
}
```